# Matlab intersection of two lines

Tags: matlab, math, intersection

I am still confused by some answers and unable to find correct one.
My goal is to find if there is some intersection between two lines.

Both lines are defined by two points

```
%first line
FPX = [x1,x2] FPY = [y1,y2]

%second line
SPX = [x1,x2] SPY = [y1,y2]
```

How can I find if lines intersect?

Comment: You need to write down the equations for the lines and solve the equation system. Matlab can help for the latter part if you express the system in terms of a matrix; see [```\```](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html)

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20091003070719/http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/lineline2d/ this is probably best working solution I found.